# custom hook in react

Tags: javascript, react.js

I have re-written [this javascript code](https://github.com/Krzysztof-Antosik/Two-direction-Sticky-Sidebar/blob/main/src/StickySidebar.js#L78) logic to a react custom hook to use.

But it seems like the solution i have made is a bit slow, and heavy on performance, I was wondering in which sort of ways I could make it more performant.

This is the custom hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { isBrowser } from '@utils/environment';
import { NAVBAR_HEIGHT_PX } from '@common/helpers';

export const useSticky = stickyElement => {
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(NAVBAR_HEIGHT_PX);
  let offsetTop = NAVBAR_HEIGHT_PX;
  let currPos = isBrowser ? window.pageYOffset : 0;
  let endScroll = isBrowser ? window.innerHeight - stickyElement?.current?.offsetHeight - 500 : 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isBrowser) {
      return undefined;
    }

    const positionStickySidebar = () => {
      const { innerHeight, scrollY } = window;

      endScroll = innerHeight - stickyElement.current.offsetHeight;

      if (window.scrollY < currPos) {
        if (offsetTop < NAVBAR_HEIGHT_PX * 2) {
          offsetTop = offsetTop + currPos - scrollY;
        } else if (offsetTop >= NAVBAR_HEIGHT_PX * 2 && offsetTop !== endScroll) {
          offsetTop = NAVBAR_HEIGHT_PX * 2;
        }
      } else {
        if (offsetTop > endScroll) {
          offsetTop = offsetTop + currPos - scrollY;
        } else if (offsetTop < (endScroll) && offsetTop !== endScroll) {
          offsetTop = endScroll;
        }
      }
      setOffset(offsetTop);
      currPos = window.scrollY;
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', positionStickySidebar, {
      capture: false,
      passive: true,
    });
    window.addEventListener('scroll', positionStickySidebar, {
      capture: false,
      passive: true,
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', positionStickySidebar);
      window.removeEventListener('resize', positionStickySidebar);
    };
  }, []);

  return offset;
};
```

This is the usage of it

```
const divRef = useRef(null);
const offsetTop = useSticky(divRef);

  <ContentContainer offsetTop={offsetTop} ref={divRef}>
```

And this is the styled component:

```
export const ContentContainer = styled.div`
  position: sticky;
  top: ${({ offsetTop }) => `${offsetTop}px`};
`;
```